# manage.py makemigrations пишет No changes detected

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu

Пытаюсь установить Django 3.0.4 на сервере Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), 64-bit (x86)
При выполнении команды `~/myprojectdir/manage.py makemigrations` выдает `No changes detected`.
Пробовал указывать в `INSTALLED_APPS` название проекта,нo не помогло.

Comment: А миграции точно есть? Надо указывать apps' config в settings, иначе, скорее всего, работать не будет

Comment: Что значит миграция точно есть? Пытаюсь установить Django в первый раз, моя база PostgreSQL пустая, после команды `~/myprojectdir/manage.py makemigrations` мне нужно выполнить команду `~/myprojectdir/manage.py migrate`.Мой settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myproject'
]`

Comment: Ну, вообще миграции делаются когда у вас есть какие-то данные в БД, и вам нужно изменить схему, вы добавили стоблец, допустим, и вот надо старые данные перенести на новую схему. Если у вас база пуста, то вроде бы Django должен внести свои какие-то таблицы в схему, так что странно, что у вас не выходит. Можете приложить полный traceback команды `manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: (myprojectenv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-0:~/myprojectdir$ ~/myprojectdir/manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

Comment: Выходит, у вас действительно нет миграций, значит можно попробовать запустить проект и посмотреть на результат. Если сервер поднимется без предупреждений, то все хорошо, вы зря волновались, если нет, то надо читать, что написали в предупреждениях

Comment: все нормально, не переживай

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы в первый раз ставите джангу, то `makemigrations` действительно выдаст это сообщение. Вместо него выполните `migrate`, чтобы применить стандартные миграции.

```
λ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

В `INSTALLED_APPS` указываются приложения, создаваемые через команду `startapp`. Название проекта в нём указывать не надо.